# After uncomment extension=pgsql in php.ini Apache HTTP Web Server restart is failed

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, php, php.ini

After I uncomment:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=pgsql в php.ini
```

Apache restart is failed and Apache did not work. I use:

> Server version: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) Apache Lounge VS16
>
> Server built: May 28 2019 17:12:51"
>
> "PHP Version 7.3.6".

It seems, that after any uncommenting one of dynamical extensions, Apache reset, or start after stop, is failing. If I use PHP with in same way changed php.ini in command-line or with built-in PHP web-server all works good and dynamical extension is loaded successfully.

If I use PHP with php.ini without any change Apache with PHP works well. What I do wrong?

Comment: Have you run e.g. `httpd -k start` with from the  bin directory of your Apache installation and/or checked the Apache logs?

Comment: Yes, I did this. But in log not any records about this bug ( LogLevel = warn). May be, I must use  LogLevel = debug instead? P.S. Now I use XAMPP. It works well.